# In numpy, multipy two structured matrices concisely

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-multiplication, kronecker-product

I have two matrices. The first has the following structure:

```
[[1, 0, a],
 [0, 1, b],
 [1, 0, c],
 [0, 1, d]]
```

where `1`, `0`, `a`, `b,` `c`, and `d` are scalars. The matrix is 4 by 3

The second is just a 2 by 3 matrix:

```
[[r1],
[r2]]
```

where `r1` and `r2` are the first and second rows respectively, each having 3 elements.
I would like the output to be:

```
[[r1, 0, a*r1],
 [0, r1, b*r1],
 [r2, 0, c*r2],
 [0, r2, d*r2]]
```

which would be a 4 by 9 matrix.
This is similar to the Kronecker product, except separately for each row of the second matrix. Of course this could be done with cumbersome loops which I want to avoid.
How can I do this concisely?

Comment: Well... `np.kron()` is the kronecker-product. So if that isn't what you want, then you are probably going to have to loop to obtain a matrix that you want.

Comment: @Shmack, I mentioned np.kron() for clarity. Looping is obvious. I'm looking for broadcacsting magic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using broadcasting, with x.shape (n, 3), and y.shape (n//2, 3):

```
out = (x.reshape(-1, 2, 3, 1) * y.reshape(-1, 1, 1, 3)).reshape(-1, 9)
```

Comment: Aah, good idea, but not quite correct. It should be `out = (x.reshape(-1, 2, 3, 1) * y[:, None, None, :]).reshape(-1, 9)`

Comment: You're totally correct... I was trying to make it as simple as possible and messed up the ordering in the process :)

Comment: Also, my OCD makes me think that it looks nicer if both x and y use reshape so you can use `y.reshape(-1, 1, 1, 3)` instead

Comment: I've updated the original solution with your suggestions. Thanks a lot

Comment: I checked the speed with timeit magic. The loop version I proposed, using kronecker's products, takes 108 us. This broadcast version only 3! This is definitely the best answer

Comment: @GianlucaMicchi,@Chrysophylaxs - that's it! Thank you, both. And yeah, the time diff is one reason to avoid explicit python loops. As well as aesthetics

Answer (score 3):

You can do exactly what you said in the last line: do a separate Kronecker product for each row of the second column and then concatenate the results.

Let's assume that the two matrices are called `x` (4 by 3) and `y` (2 by 3). The first thing to do is to split `x` in two parts because only half matrix participates in each part of the product.

```
x = x.reshape(2, 2, 3)
```

Then you can calculate the two products separately:

```
z0 = np.kron(x[0], y[0])
z1 = np.kron(x[1], y[1])
```

Finally, concatenate the two results along the first axis:

```
z = np.concatenate([z0, z1], axis=0)
```

Or if, like me, you enjoy big ugly one-liners you can do:

```
z = np.concatenate([np.kron(xr, yr) for xr, yr in zip(x.reshape(2, 2, 3), y)], axis=0)
```

---

In the general case you mentioned in the comments, it would become:

```
z = np.concatenate([np.kron(xr, yr) for xr, yr in zip(x.reshape(int(n / 2), 2, 3), y)], axis=0)
```

This gives equal results to the explicit loop, which can be numba.jit compiled I believe:

```
def solve_explicit(x, y):
    # sanity checks
    assert x.shape[0] == 2*y.shape[0]
    assert x.shape[1] == y.shape[1]

    n = x.shape[0]
    z = np.zeros((n, 9))
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(3):
            for k in range(3):
                z[i, k + 3 * j] = x[i, j] * y[int(i / 2), k]
    return z
```

Comment: Ok, it's close to what I'm looking for. But, In the general case, the first matrix is nx3 and the second is n/2 by 3. This would still require looping over n rows. Is there a way to avoid an explicit for loop?

Comment: I have updated the answer to adapt the loop to your more general use case and to provide an explicit element-by-element calculation.

Comment: However, I couldn't do the broadcasting of np.kron. I think that you always get the mixed products.

Answer (score 1):

I personally would use [np.einsum](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) in this situation because I think it's easier to understand than broadcasting.

```
import numpy as np

(a, b, c, d) = np.random.rand(4)
x = np.array([[1, 0, a], [0, 1, b], [1, 0, c], [0, 1, d]])
y = np.random.rand(2, 3)
z = np.einsum("ij,ik->ijk", x.reshape(-1, 6), y).reshape(-1, 9)

# timeit magic commands.
# %timeit -n 50000 np.einsum("ij,ik->ijk", x.reshape(-1, 6), y).reshape(-1, 9)
# %timeit -n 50000 (x.reshape(-1, 2, 3, 1) * y.reshape(-1, 1, 1, 3)).reshape(-1, 9)
```

Some good references on Einstein summation in NumPy: [[2](https://obilaniu6266h16.wordpress.com/2016/02/04/einstein-summation-in-numpy/), [3](https://ajcr.net/Basic-guide-to-einsum/), [4](https://rockt.github.io/2018/04/30/einsum)].

Comment: much more readable. do you know what's the runtime, compared to broadcast?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, I tried to do some timeit magic. The broadcast and einsum method are basically as fast as each other (respectively, 1.8 v 1.88 us), but the numba.jit compiled version of the explicit loop blows them both out of the water: 560 ns (after the first pass that is slower because it requires numba to jit compile the function).

Comment: Yes, I suppose it really depends on what the goal is! If speed is paramount, then Numba is the best bet. If it's a single line in some code for a scientific publication where a microsecond won't make a difference, then I prefer the readability of `einsum`. Hopefully Numba will support `einsum` someday and and the trade-off between readability and speed won't be necessary.